# How to extract multiple text and numbers from a string using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

How can I extract 3 or more separate text from a line using 'sed'

I have the following line:

```
echo <MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>
```

So far I am able to extract the 'DOB-029' by doing

```
sed -n 's/.*\(DOB-[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

but I am not getting the other texts such as the name or the post.

My expected output should be **Mike** **DOB-029** **Post-555**

Edited

Say I have a list within a file and I want to extract specific text/IDs from the entire list and save it to a .txt file

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: my expected output should be Mike DOB-029 Post-555

Comment: And what about the last block `/Male`? What is the logic underlying the problem? Extract everything `/` separated?

Comment: I don't want everything. The aim is to show only the first 3 text separated by '/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed 's/.*[\(.*\).\(DOB-[0-9]*\).\(Post-[0-9]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/'` should do the trick!

Parts in between `\(` and `\)` are captured strings that can be called upon using `\i` with `i` the index of the group.

Script for custom use:

```
#! /bin/bash


fields=${1:-123}
file='/path/to/input'

name=$(sed 's/.*\[\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\1/' $file)
dob=$(sed 's/.*\(DOB-[0-9]*\).*/\1/' $file)
post=$(sed 's/.*\(Post-[0-9]*\).*/\1/' $file)

[[ $fields =~ .*1.* ]] && output=$name
[[ $fields =~ .*2.* ]] && output="$output $dob"
[[ $fields =~ .*3.* ]] && output="$output $post"

echo $output
```

Set the file with the line you want to parse in the `file` variable (I can add more functionality such as supplying the file as argument or getting it from a larger file if you like). And execute the script with an int argument, if this int contains '1' it will display name, if 2, it will display DOB and 3 will output post information. You can combine to e.g. '123' or '32' or whichever combination you like.

**Stdin**

If you want to read from stdin, use following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

line=$(cat /dev/stdin)

fields=${1:-123}

name=$(echo $line | sed 's/.*\[\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\1/')
dob=$(echo $line | sed 's/.*\(DOB-[0-9]*\).*/\1/')
post=$(echo $line | sed 's/.*\(Post-[0-9]*\).*/\1/')

[[ $fields =~ .*1.* ]] && output=$name
[[ $fields =~ .*2.* ]] && output="$output $dob"
[[ $fields =~ .*3.* ]] && output="$output $post"

echo $output
```

Example usage:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ echo '<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>' | ./script.sh 123
Mike DOB-029 Post-555
$ echo '<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>' | ./script.sh 12
Mike DOB-029
$ echo '<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>' | ./script.sh 32
DOB-029 Post-555
$ echo '<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>' | ./script.sh 
Mike DOB-029 Post-555
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this code or create a script so I have the option to take text at different times? So if I want to take the Name only or the DOB-029 or Post-555 or both

Comment: My pleasure, you can thank me by accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

A solution with **awk:**

```
echo "<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>" | awk -F[/[] '{print $2, $3, $4}'
```

We set the delimiter as `/` or `[` (`-F[/[]`). then we just print the fields `$2, $3 and $4` which are the `2nd, 3rd and 4th fields` respectively.

With **sed:**

```
echo "<MX><[Mike/DOB-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>" | sed 's/\(^.*\[\)\(.*\)\(\/[^/]*$\)/\2/; s/\// /g'
```

Comment: i fell in love recently.. :-)

Comment: If the OP didn't request it for `sed`, I'd have suggested `awk` too. A scripting language with the power of a programming language, there's just no way to beat it :)

Comment: That is a good idea but it may not work on all the fields I may have, what if the fields are not consistent among multiply files? So the DOB-029 may not be in the 2nd field all the time

Comment: @Mikey: Modify your question please, with different scenarios...

Comment: @Mikey: or give a scenario where this is not working.. we can fix that up then.

Answer (score 1):

use the bash substitution builtins.

```
line="<MX><[Mike/D0B-029/Post-555/Male]><MX>"; 
linel=${line/*[/}; liner=${linel%\/*}; echo ${liner//\// }
```